# connect two elements with line in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, treeview

I'm trying to creating a family tree in html. [Here's the fillde](https://jsfiddle.net/krishnathota/h70vqLbz/3/).

In this what I'm doing is, enter the no. of children and click generate child. And click on a parent and again do the same. It generates childs to that. so it goes on. 
I need to connect the parent to child with lines.
I think there are multiple ways like svg, canvas but not sure how
Can you suggest me a simple way to achieve this?

[image: Output]

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="title"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter Name1:</td>
    <td>
      <input id="txtName1" type="text">
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input type="button" id="btnUpdate1" value="Update 1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter Name2:</td>
    <td>
      <input id="txtName2" type="text">
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input type="button" id="btnUpdate2" value="Update 2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter No of Children:</td>
    <td>
      <input id="txtChilds" type="number">
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input type="button" id="btnGenerate" value="Generate" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="divFamilyTree">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#divFamilyTree').on('click', 'table', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("member")) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      $('#divFamilyTree').find('table').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  });

  $('#btnUpdate1').click(function() {
    var ft = $('#divFamilyTree');
    var selected = ft.find('table.selected');
    selected.find('.name1:first').html($('#txtName1').val());
  });

  $('#btnGenerate').click(function() {
    var ft = $('#divFamilyTree');
    var selected = ft.find('table.selected');
    var childs = $('#txtChilds').val();
    if (childs > 0) {
      if (ft.find('table').length > 0) {
        if (selected.length != 0) {
          selected.find('.child').remove();
          selected.append('<tr class="child"><td></td></tr>');
          var td = selected.find('tr.child>td')
          for (i = 0; i < childs; i++)
            td.append('<table><tr><td><table class="member"><tr><td class="name1">Person 1</td><td class="name2">Person 2</td></tr></table></td></tr></td></table>');
        }
      } else {
        for (i = 0; i < childs; i++)
          ft.append('<table><tr><td><table class="member"><tr><td class="name1">Person 1</td><td class="name2">Person 2</td></tr></table></td></tr></td></table>');
      }
    }
  })
});
```

**CSS**

```
 .selected {
   background-color: lightgrey;
 }

 #divFamilyTree {
   text-align: center;
 }

 table {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
 }

 #divFamilyTree,
 td,
 tr {
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

Comment: put code in OP not only link to fiddle

Comment: What is OP that you've mentioned ?

Comment: OP is "Original Post"
I would say just leave it in the fiddle, it is easier to understand this way

I would suggest maybe learning about HTML5's canvas, you can do what you're doing very easily there.

Comment: @Sean_A91 other people wouldnt waste time going on another page just to check your code and those other might know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out using `HTML5 Canvas`. Thanks to @Sean_A91

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krishnathota/h70vqLbz/9/)